# What is the difference between AWS WAF and AWS GuardDuty?

Tags: amazon-web-services

AWS WAF is a web application firewall that helps protect your web applications from common web exploits that could affect application availability, compromise security, or consume excessive resources.

Amazon GuardDuty is a managed threat detection service that continuously monitors for malicious or unauthorized behavior to help you protect your AWS accounts and workloads. It monitors for activity such as unusual API calls or potentially unauthorized deployments that indicate a possible account compromise. GuardDuty also detects potentially compromised instances or reconnaissance by attackers.

Please help me clarify the difference. Is Guard Duty like an anti-virus for the whole account and WAF an auto configured intelligent network firewall ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

AWS WAF is a web application firewall which is able to be configured in front of your web application where it will monitor http requests and prevent any halmful ones. This is only for web traffic.

In contrast Amazon GuardDuty is an active intruder detection system which constantly monitors suspected configuration changes and anomalies in your AWS account and notifies relevant parties for further actions.

Your understanding is correct where GuardDuty is like an antivirus for the whole AWS account while WAF is a specialized firewall for web traffic for a configured web application.

Comment: AWS GuardDuty can **detect** potential threats., it can’t prevent. AWS WAF operates at the application layer and is designed to **protect** web applications from common exploits such as SQL injection and cross-site scripting. AWS Network Firewall operates at the network level and can actively **block** malicious connections before it reaches your application.